# Ignore NaN in numpy bincount in python

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have a 1D array and I want to use `numpy bincount` to create a histogram. It works OK, but **I want it to ignore NaN values.**

```
histogram = np.bincount(distancesArray, weights=intensitiesArray) / np.bincount(distancesArray)
```

**How can I do that?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I think your problem is:

```
import numpy

w = numpy.array([0.3, float("nan"), 0.2, 0.7, 1., -0.6]) # weights
x = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
numpy.bincount(x,  weights=w)
#>>> array([ 0.3,  nan,  1.1])
```

The solution is just to use indexing to only keep the non-nan weights:

```
keep = ~numpy.isnan(w)
numpy.bincount(x[keep],  weights=w[keep])
#>>> array([ 0.3,  0.2,  1.1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have `NaN` in an integer valued array. If you try to call `np.bincount`, it is going to complain:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

If you do the casting (`.astype(int)`), you will get crazy values, like -9223372036854775808. You can overcome this by selecting the non NaN values:

```
mask = ~np.logical_or(np.isnan(distancesArray), np.isnan(intensitiesArray))
histogram = np.bincount(distancesArray[mask].astype(int), 
                        weights=intensitiesArray[mask])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert it to a pandas Series and remove the null values.

```
ds = pd.Series(distancesArray)
ds = ds[ds.notnull()]   #returns non nullvalues
```